# Exception : main java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Tags: android, bitmap, out-of-memory, fatal-error, bitmapimage

I get this error sometimes when I run my app. There is no problem when i compile the application. Sometimes it breaks an i get this message from logcat :

E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:596)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
            at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:832)
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2988)
            at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1558)
            at android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable.inflate(AnimationDrawable.java:282)
            at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:937)
            at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:873)
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2970)
            at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1558)
            at android.view.View.setBackgroundResource(View.java:15697)
            at com.dilisim.hayvanlaralemi.play.PlayActivity.playGoodJob(PlayActivity.java:185)
            at com.dilisim.hayvanlaralemi.play.PlayActivity$2.onClick(PlayActivity.java:144)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4475)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18786)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: try to look at recommendations for displaying bitmaps efficiently
http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Comment: i added 'android:largeHeap="true"' in manifest to solve problem.

Answer (score 1):

i added 'android:largeHeap="true"' in manifest to solve problem.

Answer (score 0):

Surely it is because some of the structures that you use in the program exceeds the maximum defined size (probably a bitmap) but could be an array or other structure

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're doing too much work at same time.
Use Volley or ImageLoader, that works like a charm.